# Sorting XML file by attribute

Tags: c#, .net, xml, sorting

I have a following XML code:

```
<Group>
    <GElement code="x">
        <Group>
            <GElement code="x">
                <fname>a</fname>
                <lname>b</lname>
            </GElement>
            <GElement code ="f">
                <fname>fa</fname>
            </GElement>
        </Group>
    </GElement>
    <GElement code ="f">
    </GElement>
</Group>
```

I would like to have the output sorted by "code" like:

```
<Group>
    <GElement code ="f">
    </GElement>
    <GElement code="x">
        <Group>
            <GElement code ="f">
                <fname>fa</fname>
            </GElement>
            <GElement code="x">
                <fname>a</fname>
                <lname>b</lname>
            </GElement>
        </Group>
    </GElement>
</Group>
```

The depth of the tree can be endless i.e. the GElement can have another Group and so on.

Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect there's an XSL solution for this but I'm not posting as an answer because I'm not entirely certain.

Comment: The minute you start fretting about how your XML looks is the moment you realize you have too much time on your hands.

Comment: @Will: This may be true for indentation, but document order carries meaning in XML, so why not implement something that relies on document order as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `XslCompiledTransform` ([see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx))  to apply this styleshet to your XML document:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
  <!-- the identity template copies everything verbatim -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- special template for <Group> that sorts its children -->
  <xsl:template match="Group">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*" /> <!-- copy attributes, if any -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="GElement">
        <xsl:sort select="@code" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML tree nesting depth can be arbitrary.

Comment: ...yeah, something like this, was what I was thinking.

Comment: @tomalak, your first xsl:template has an xsl:apply-templates end tag

Comment: also, is `<xsl:copy-of select="@*" />` necessary? is there any difference in the output if you remove it?

Comment: @DevNull: You're right. Corrected. No, there is no difference in the output with that particular input. But if there are attributes defined in the *actual* XML, they'll be copied. The `<xsl:copy-of select="@*" />` does not hurt or take away performance, but it makes the solution correct.

Comment: @DevNull, thinking about it, to be *really* correct, the solution would also need an `<xsl:copy-of select="node()[not(self::GElement])" />`, but I estimated that contained elements other than `<GElement>` were unlikely. This estimate could be wrong, so I add it as a comment. :)

Comment: Amazing solution. I tried on my huge file and it worked. Thanks a lot.