# Format XML file content

Tags: xml, xslt

I know there are many questions about formatting an `XML` file using an `XSL` `stylesheet`. However I am not trying to format the *output*, but the file content itself. What I mean is that I currently have an `XML` file (it is a `SolidWorks` material library) and you cannot automatically alphabetize the *output* of the `XML` file, I actually have to alphabetize the *content* of the `XML` file.

Is there a way to do this? Please see below for a snapshot of what I mean.

Thanks! I should note that I have basically zero experience in `XML` or `XSL` but do code a fair bit so please be patient.

Here is a simplified version of what I have:

```
<mstns:materials xmlns:mstns="http://www.solidworks.com/sldmaterials" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:sldcolorswatch="http://www.solidworks.com/sldcolorswatch" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2008.03">
   <classification name="Aluminum Alloy">
   <classification name="Steel">
   <classification name="Copper">
   <classification name="Rubber">
</mstns:materials>
```

This is what I want to convert it to:

```
<mstns:materials xmlns:mstns="http://www.solidworks.com/sldmaterials" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:sldcolorswatch="http://www.solidworks.com/sldcolorswatch" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2008.03">
   <classification name="Aluminum Alloy">
   <classification name="Copper">
   <classification name="Rubber">
   <classification name="Steel">
</mstns:materials>
```

(i.e. alphabetize the classification sections).

Now I'm pretty sure I need to use `XLST`but I'm not sure about my code or really how to even implement it to either output a new `XML` file or in a web browser or something. Here is what I have so far (which I lifted pretty much line for line from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782838/sorting-xml-file-by-attribute/2782917#2782917):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- the identity template copies everything verbatim -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <!-- special template for <Group> that sorts its children -->
 <xsl:template match="mstns:materials">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:copy-of select="@*" /> <!-- copy attributes, if any -->
     <xsl:apply-templates select="classification">
        <xsl:sort select="@name" order="ascending"/>
     </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. XSLT can transform your XML input - but it will not modify the original XML file (unless you tell the application that initiates the transformation to overwrite the source file with the result).

Comment: I am trying to modify the original `XML` file. Any way to do this?

Comment: How do you plan on initiating the transformation?

Comment: That is sort of part of my question; I don't know how. (I should reiterate just how little I have dealt with `XML`)

Comment: This part of of your question is not about XSLT as such (i.e. what should be the contents of your stylesheet), but about running the transformation process itself. You can do this in a variety of ways, the most basic, I think, would be by using the command line. If you're comfortable using C (as your profile says), then have a look at: http://xmlsoft.org/libxslt/

Comment: Great! I'll take a look (hopefully) within the next few days to see if I can get this up and running. Cheers :)